# Haskell Handle doesn't close properly

Tags: haskell

```
import GHC.Conc (pseq)

import System.Directory (removeFile, renameFile)
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let fp = "handleCollision.txt"
    h <- openFile fp ReadMode
    l <- hGetLine h
    (hClose h) `pseq` (func fp)

func :: FilePath -> IO ()
func fp = do
    h <- openFile fp ReadMode
    cont <- hGetContents h
    chk <- openFile ('.':fp) WriteMode >>= (\h -> hPutStrLn h (unlines . map (map succ) $ lines cont) >> hClose h)
    chk `pseq` (hClose h `pseq` removeFile fp)
    renameFile ('.':fp) fp
```

In the code above, the result of calling main is an error in the attempt to remove the file referred to by fp.

> *** Exception: DeleteFile "handleCollision.txt": permission denied (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)

If I only call 'func "handleCollision.txt"', then no error occurs. Why does the Handle in main seem to collide with the deletion of fp in func despite the fact that 'hClose h' is treated as strict and 'func fp' is treated as lazy?

Comment: Since [there's no documentation for GHC.Conc.pseq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/GHC-Conc.html#v:pseq), would you mind explaining what it means?

Comment: Your code never executes `hClose h`.

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to: `main :: IO (); main = do (putStrLn "foo") \`pseq\` (putStrLn "bar")`

Comment: This isn't even an issue with `pseq`. You can try @melpomene's example with `seq` instead.

Comment: By the way, `hGetContents` already closes the handle.

Comment: @ChrisMartin `parallel` re-exports [`pseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.1/docs/Control-Parallel.html#v:pseq) with some extra docs. :)

Comment: @Alec Ah, thank you. Though I suppose I ought to have known immediately from the type `a -> b -> b` that it discards its first argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `Control.Parallel.pseq` instead of `GHC.Conc.pseq` for portability. However, it does not do what you think it does.

`pseq` only forces evaluation to [WHNF](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form). For the expression `(hClose h) :: IO ()`, the WNHF is exactly that - the representation of an `IO` action. It does *not* perform the action.

Just take out the `pseq`. Better yet, use methods like [`withFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:withFile) to avoid manually tracking file open and close.

```
main = do
    let fp = "handleCollision.txt"
    l <- withFile fp ReadMode hGetLine
    func fp

func fp = do
    cont <- readFile fp
    writeFile ('.':fp) $ unlines $ map (map succ) $ lines cont
    renameFile ('.':fp) fp
```